# ngrx : Action that doesn't change state

Tags: angular, ngrx, reducers, ngrx-store

I perform a function(click) in UI which makes API call. If the call fails, i dispatch an ngrx action with the error message in the payload. I use a reducer to store this error in the state. In the UI, I show a pop-up whenever the error in the state changes. Now, when 2 consecutive error messages returned are same, the state gets updated twice with the same value. So, apparently, there is no change in state during second time. So, I don't get a pop for the second error message. But, I need to get pop-up every time an error message comes.

Is this possible without dispatching a NEW action that will clear the error message when the pop-up is acknowledged. I don't want to create a new action just to clear the error message in state.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is wrapping that response message (I suppose is a string value) in an interface.

That way, whenever you capture an error, you create a new wrapper object in order to force the equality check for that state property to always be false.

Something like:

```
interface ErrorWrapper {
   message: string;
}

export const string ERROR = "[Error] Something just exploded";

class ErrorCapturedAction implements Action {
  readonly type = ERROR;
  constructor(public readonly payload: ErrorWrapper){}
}

export type Actions = ErrorCapturedAction;    

interface State {
   error: ErrorWrapper | null;
}


initialState: State = {error = null};

reducer(state = initialState, action: Actions): State {
  switch(action.type){
  ...
    case ERROR:
      const error = action.payload;
      return {...state, error};
  ...
  }
}
```